# Eliminar duplicados de un arreglo de objetos JSON en javascript (Angular 5)

Tags: javascript, json, array, objeto

Estoy intentando eliminar los elementos duplicados dentro de un objeto json que esta en un arreglo pero no logro poder hacerlo, intente con filter y con map pero al parece no logro acceder al objeto json es decir hacer referencia a el, aquí muestro un ejemplo del arreglo:

```
const q = [
  { zone: { _id: 'zone1', name: 'zone1' }, _id2: '143', name: 'ZONA1ALCALA' },
  { zone: { _id: 'zone1', name: 'zone1' }, _id2: '144', name: 'ZONA1OTRO' },
  { zone: { _id: 'zone2', name: 'zone2' }, _id2: '145', name: 'ZONA2OTRO MAS' },
  { _id: '146', name: 'ALBACETE' }
];
```

Y lo que quisiera es poder eliminar el elemento repetido zone1 dentor del objeto zone que esta en el arreglo, por ejempplo deberia devolver algo asi:

```
const result = [
  { zone: { _id: 'zone1', name: 'zone1' }, _id2: '144', name: 'ZONA1OTRO' },
  { zone: { _id: 'zone2', name: 'zone2' }, _id2: '145', name: 'ZONA2OTRO MAS' },
  { _id: '146', name: 'ALBACETE' }
];
```

Apreciaría mucho cualquier ayuda, estoy intentado de muchas formas todo el día y no lo logre aun poder hacerlo.

Answer (score 1):

```
function removeDuplicates(arrayIn) {
    var arrayOut = [];
    arrayIn.forEach(item=> {
      try {
        if (JSON.stringify(arrayOut[arrayOut.length-1].zone) !== JSON.stringify(item.zone)) {
          arrayOut.push(item);
        }
      } catch(err) {
        arrayOut.push(item);
       }
    })
    return arrayOut;
}
```

con el `forEach` recorro todo el array y para poder comparar dos JSONs paso el JSON  a string con la funcion `JSON.stringify()` y luego los comparo y si hay mas de un elemento repetido de este tipo `zone: { _id: 'zone#', name: 'zone#' }` solo agrego uno y si el JSON no tiene `zona:` lo agrego, para eso es el `try - catch`

Comment: Excelente! funciona perfecto... muchas gracias. Ademas gracias también por explicar el código. Solo tengo una duda: porque hay que pasar el JSON a string? no se puede acceder directamente al objeto JSON por un indice?.

Comment: porque al comparar 2 JSON así aparentemente sean iguales no lo son ejemplo: a = {a:1}, b= {a:1} en JavaScript al hacer a === b esto es igual a false, en cambio si lo cambio a string  a = "{a:1}", b= "{a:1}", a === b es igual a true

Comment: Disculpa podrías decirme en todo caso si fuera necesario solo comparar por ejemplo el _id que esta dentro de zone como seria?

Comment: AL parecer no funciona, agregue dos registros mas igual los repite.

Comment: Si intentamos esto no funciona:

Comment: const q = [
    { zone: { _id: 'zone1', name: 'zone1' }, _id2: '143', name: 'ZONA1ALCALA' },
    { zone: { _id: 'zone1', name: 'zone1' }, _id2: '143', name: 'ZONA1ALCALA' },
    { zone: { _id: 'zone1', name: 'zone1' }, _id2: '143', name: 'ZONA1ALCALA' },
    { zone: { _id: 'zone1', name: 'zone1' }, _id2: '144', name: 'ZONA1OTRO' },
    { zone: { _id: 'zone2', name: 'zone2' }, _id2: '145', name: 'ZONA2OTRO MAS' },
    { _id: '146', name: 'ALBACETE' }
  ];

Answer (score 0):

Puedes simplificar el arreglo utilizando un hashtable como cache. Si deseas que aparezca el ultimo duplicado solo tienes que invertir el arreglo. Ejemplo aca:

```
var qcache = {};
var nuevo = q.reverse().filter(e => {
  return e.zone ? (qcache[e.zone._id] ? false : qcache[e.zone._id] = 1) : true;
}).reverse();

console.log(nuevo);
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes eliminar los duplicados de la siguiente manera.

```js
var arrExamenes = [
    {
      "nom": "SIM NIV 1",
      "fecha": "2023-02-27",
      "codlocal": "6",
      "nomlocal": "Edificio",
      "tipo": "1",
      "grupo": "REGULAR"
    },
    {
      "nom": "SIM NIV 1",
      "fecha": "2023-02-27",
      "codlocal": "9",
      "nomlocal": "Faucett",
      "tipo": "1",
      "grupo": "REGULAR"
    },
    {
      "nom": "SIM NIV 1",
      "fecha": "2023-02-27",
      "codlocal": "74",
      "nomlocal": "Universitaria",
      "tipo": "1",
      "grupo": "REGULAR"
    },
    {
      "nom": "SIM NIV 1",
      "fecha": "2023-02-27",
      "codlocal": "132",
      "nomlocal": "Virtual",
      "tipo": "1",
      "grupo": "REGULAR"
    },
    {
      "nom": "SIM NIV 2",
      "fecha": "2023-03-06",
      "codlocal": "6",
      "nomlocal": "Edificio",
      "tipo": "1",
      "grupo": "REGULAR"
    },
    {
      "nom": "SIM NIV 2",
      "fecha": "2023-03-06",
      "codlocal": "9",
      "nomlocal": "Faucett",
      "tipo": "1",
      "grupo": "REGULAR"
    },
    {
      "nom": "SIM NIV 2",
      "fecha": "2023-03-06",
      "codlocal": "74",
      "nomlocal": "Universitaria",
      "tipo": "1",
      "grupo": "REGULAR"
    },
    {
      "nom": "SIM NIV 2",
      "fecha": "2023-03-06",
      "codlocal": "132",
      "nomlocal": "Virtual",
      "tipo": "1",
      "grupo": "REGULAR"
    },
    {
      "nom": "SIM 13",
      "fecha": "2023-03-13",
      "codlocal": "6",
      "nomlocal": "Edificio",
      "tipo": "1",
      "grupo": "REGULAR"
    }
  ];

var arrNombres = [];
let anterior = "";
$.each(arrExamenes, function(index, value) {
    let nuevo = value.nom;
    if ( nuevo != anterior ) { 
        arrNombres.push({"nom":value.nom, "fec":value.fecha}); 
    } 
    anterior = nuevo;
});
console.log(arrNombres);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Saludos.

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).